# Android - How to read large JSON data effectively

Tags: android

I am beginning Android Development. I am reading large JSON data from the server. How can I process this data effectively.

Thank You.

Comment: That would depend on the language that the server is running, as well as what "large" is, exactly.

Comment: What does Android have to do with this?

Comment: You mean you want your application to parse an inordinately large JSON response from the server? How large is it and what happens when you try? We need a _lot_ more information to help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about speed then I'd recommend [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation). It's very fast: http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/cat_performance.html

OTOH, your network latency is going to be much greater then the time it takes to parse JSON. So in real-world conditions speed of parsing is not going to affect you app speed much.

Answer (score 0):

Another library is GSON which I am using in my project: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Please take the effort to post more information along with your question.

Answer (score 0):

With the constraint memory of the handsets, the question of parsing huge amounts of data becomes a question of space before it becomes a question of speed. The built-in org.json library may not be best in speed, but limiting the dataset.to.process may have a much larger impact on overall performance than selecting a different library that uses a few cycless less.